How can a Jest test use $(...) in the same way that browser JS can?
I'm just starting setting up jest tests for a browser-based application. I haven't used jest before.
I thought I'd fixed it so that $("...") would work as it does with jquery in a browser. But it doesn't: it returns undefined. What am I missing?
The error produced is
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'val')

when running this test in __test__/whatever.test.js :
beforeAll(() => {
        document.body.innerHTML = 'some html';
});

describe('wombat', () => {
        beforeAll(() => {
                $('#spong').val('dfd');
        });
        it("does something", () => {
                $("#reflecting").val('dfd');
        });
});

My jest.setup.js is
const $ = require('./jquery.min.js');
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;

my jest.config.js is
const config = {
  automock: true,
  coverageProvider: "v8",
  setupFiles: [
          './jest.setup.js',
  ],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  verbose: true,
};
module.exports = config;

and my babel.config.js is
module.exports = {presets: ['@babel/preset-env']};

TIA. <3
